# Cyclic dependency check using EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following requirement whilst using EF Core 3. I have Exercises with (Id = 1 Pushup), (Id = 2 Squat), (Id = 3 Weight Lift) and users. Once one exercise is completed, one ore more new exercise(s) are created. A multilevel hierarcy can be created with n level.
I have an issue though that can cause cyclic dependencies to the exercices. 
e.g Pushup (1) is completed. Squat (2) is created. Squat (2) is completed then Weight Lift (3) is created. There is also a dependency on Weight Lift (3) that once it is completed it creates Pushup(1) with leads to cyclic dependency and I need to avoid that.
I gave a very simple example. In my project, dependencies can go up to level 50 and I dont know how to check for cyclic reference and avoid them.
Below is the code:

```
public class Exercise
{
    public Exercise()
    {
        ExerciseDependencyExercises = new HashSet<ExercisesDependency>();
        ExerciseDependencyTargetExercises = new HashSet<ExercisesDependency>();
        UserExercises = new HashSet<UserExercise>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ExercisesDependency> ExerciseDependencyExercises { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExercisesDependency> ExerciseDependencyTargetExercises { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserExercise> UserExercises { get; set; }
}

public class UserExercise
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public long ExerciseId { get; set; }
}

public class ExercisesDependency
{
    public long ExerciseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Exercise Exercise { get; set; }

    public long TargetExerciseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Exercise TargetExercise { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution I can think of is to not have your requirements dictate primary keys values (which should only be used to uniquely identify a record).

I don't know/understand why you have this requirement. But I would suggest just continue numbering, and while creating the new records to calculate whether it should be an exercise of type 1, 2 or 3. e.g. 1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>3, 4=>1, 5=>2, 6=>3, 7=>1.

Then a simple: var type = ((id - 1) %3) + 1; returns that list of numbers.

Comment: sorry I dont understand ```` do not have your requirements dictate primary keys values````. The ExericesDependency is a many to many table (EF Core way of creating M2M relationships)

Comment: Ok, I think we're misunderstanding each other, specifically related to the use of the word 'completed' in your description.

I understand your question to be... I need to set things up such that when a user completes Exercise 1, i.e. marks the Exercise 1 as completed, then a new Exercise needs to be created with id number 2.

If that's not what you're trying to do, then maybe you can elaborate what you mean with completing an exercise?

Comment: maybe my example was bad. I updated the entire problem to simulate the issue. Sorry for the bad explanation